# Option value not getting updated until page refresh in WordPress

Tags: plugins, php, functions, css, html

I am building my WordPress plugin. There, at first I am using a checkbox, and then updating the value from the checkbox (yes or no) in the Database. Then, from later on I am fetching the value form the DB, and doing some actions using a logic. But, my problem is the action that I have set on logic (like if the checkbox is 'yes' do this) doesn't work when I click on Save Changes. I need to refresh the page, then it starts to work. But the values in the DB gets updated perfectly when I click Save. I need to refresh the page again after clicking Save to make the actions happen which are under the logic. This is my code where I am displaying the checkbox, and then updating the value in the DB to 'yes' or 'no':

```
function my_plugin_settings(){
    ?>
<form method=post>
    <?php
    if(!empty($_POST['checkbox_value'])) {
          
        $recieved1=$_POST['checkbox_value'];
            update_option('checkbox_value', $recieved1, $autoload = 'yes');  
          }
    $value1 = get_option( 'checkbox_value' );
    ?>
    <input type='hidden' name='checkbox_value' value='no'>
    <label><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox_value' <?php 
    checked( esc_attr( $value1 ), 'yes' );
    ?> value='yes'> <?php 
    esc_attr_e( 'Check this box or uncheck it' );
    ?></label></br>
    <div>
        <?php submit_button(); ?>
      </div>
    </form>

    <?php

}
```

Here is my code where I am fetching the option from the DB and performing some actions.

```
if ( (get_option('checkbox_value')) == 'yes') {
    echo 'Helloxcaercfwerfgetg5 tcectg3d5euhudheufeuhufhurhf';
}
```

Any suggestions on this? Anything I am doing wrong? The above text is not getting displayed after I click Save. I need to refresh again to make the echo happen. TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be a number of reasons for this, some of which involve db cacheing.

If all this is happening on the same page, the best way to handle it is to eliminate the extra db calls as they are not really necessary anyway.  Instead, put the value into a variable (set it as global if necessary to pick it up in another function) and then use the variable instead of `get_option()`.  That way, you only have one db call and one established value.

Also, be sure to sanitize the value before you insert it in the db.

```
function my_plugin_settings(){
    ?>
    <form method=post>
    <?php

    global $value1;
    if( isset( $_POST['checkbox_value'] ) ) {
          
        $value1 = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['checkbox_value'] );
        update_option('checkbox_value', $value1, $autoload = 'yes');  
    } else {
        $value1 = get_option( 'checkbox_value' );
    }

    ?>
    <input type='hidden' name='checkbox_value' value='no'>
    <label><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox_value' <?php 
    checked( esc_attr( $value1 ), 'yes' );
    ?> value='yes'> <?php 
    esc_attr_e( 'Check this box or uncheck it' );
    ?></label></br>
    <div>
        <?php submit_button(); ?>
      </div>
    </form>

    <?php

}
```

Then, if you have to pick it up elsewhere, use the global value:

```
global $value1;
if ( 'yes' == $value1 ) {
    echo 'Helloxcaercfwerfgetg5 tcectg3d5euhudheufeuhufhurhf';
}
```

**Update**

If what you're doing involves things that happen *before* `my_plugin_settings()` (as noted in the comments), that would certainly explain the problem.  Since your OP lacks that context, I can't address it with specifics, but I can give you a general idea of what you need to look at.  You need to make sure that what you're doing happens in the proper order.  Here's a change to the code you're using to make sure the value is handled early so that your use of it later can pick things up appropriately.

```
// Do this early.
add_action( 'admin_init', function() {
    // globalize $value1 so you can pick it up later
    global $value1;
    if( isset( $_POST['checkbox_value'] ) ) {
            
        $value1 = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['checkbox_value'] );
        update_option('checkbox_value', $value1, $autoload = 'yes');  
    } else {
        $value1 = get_option( 'checkbox_value' );
    }
});

function my_plugin_settings(){
    // Wherever you use this needs to happen later than admin_init
    global $value1;
    ?>
    <form method=post>
    <input type='hidden' name='checkbox_value' value='no'>
    <label><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox_value' <?php 
    checked( esc_attr( $value1 ), 'yes' );
    ?> value='yes'> <?php 
    esc_attr_e( 'Check this box or uncheck it' );
    ?></label></br>
    <div>
        <?php submit_button(); ?>
        </div>
    </form>

    <?php
}
```

Now, anywhere you do the following needs to happen **later than** the `admin_init` action hook (or you need to use an earlier action for picking up the post value)

```
// Anything like this needs to happen later than admin_init
global $value1;
if ( 'yes' == $value1 ) {
    echo 'Helloxcaercfwerfgetg5 tcectg3d5euhudheufeuhufhurhf';
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for that. unfortunately, it didn't work out. I tried the code structure you shared. Same result :( I need to refresh the page after hitting Save to make the actions happen of those which are under the logic.

Comment: Since we don't have the entire context of this, we don't know "order of operations". So my guess would be that whatever you have your processes hooked to, that they are out of sequence (i.e. what you're doing in your `my_plugin_settings()` function is happening after the other parts, not before). You need to look at the actions you have things hooked to and make sure that you've considered the order in which things occur. I added an update to the answer to show this in a more practical way.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yeah, you were right. My function was getting executed after I had fetched the value. That is the leading cause of it. I will solve that; thanks again, man.

Comment: No problem - glad that you were able to track things down.